# GWT compile causes SIGSEGV

Tags: java, maven, gwt, segmentation-fault, gwt-maven-plugin

Does anyone know what could be causing GWT compilation failure between gwt-maven-plugin start and "Compiling module" statement?

We run GWT with info normally so all I see in my log is plugin start followed by SIGSEGV soon after.  When I run with debug locally and don't see the problem I can see that the violation gets thrown while GWT plugin is performing one of these steps:

- loads inherited modules
- reviews "Public resources found in..."   (I see two warnings for .pom files found in the classpath)
- Translatable source found in...
- Persistent unit cache dir set
- Looking for previously cached Compilation Units.

I'm starting from a clean directory so I and my cache is under target so I don't think it is in the last two.  Since the error relates to a zip lib entry, I suspect classpath and resolution is the likely issue.

**env**

jdk 1.7.0 u55 + gwt 2.5.1 + gwt-maven-plugin 2.5.1-rc1

**Please let me know if you have any ideas, I'm increasing log level, changing memory and hoping for a reproducible case.   Thanks**

**Options**

- Increase GWT memory and limit worker threads (DONE: 1 thread, 4g heap, no change)
- upgrade plugin to 2.5.1 or 2.6.1
- upgrade jdk to u67
- upgrade gwt to 2.6.1

**except**

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1-rc1:compile (default) @ mymodule ---
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000036a3089aab, pid=14610, tid=140310347593472
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x89aab]  memcpy+0x15b
...
...
Stack: [0x00007f9c8c5d3000,0x00007f9c8c6d4000],  sp=0x00007f9c8c6d0c68,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x89aab]  memcpy+0x15b
C  [libzip.so+0x50b0]  ZIP_GetEntry+0xd0
C  [libzip.so+0x3eed]  Java_java_util_zip_ZipFile_getEntry+0xad
J  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(J[BZ)J

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(J[BZ)J
J  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;
J  java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;
j  sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getEntry(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;+2
j  sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect()V+62
j  sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream()Ljava/io/InputStream;+1
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/InputStream;+18
J  org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.AbstractGwtModuleMojo.readModule(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/codehaus/mojo/gwt/GwtModule;
j  org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getLocalInherits()Ljava/util/Set;+74
j  org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.addInheritedModules(Ljava/util/Set;Ljava/util/Set;)V+42
j  org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getInherits()Ljava/util/Set;+32
j  org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getEntryPoints()Ljava/util/List;+20
j  org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compilationRequired(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;)Z+35
j  org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile([Ljava/lang/String;)V+432
j  org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute()V+57
j  org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute()V+1
j  org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution;)V+166
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ProjectIndex;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/DependencyContext;)V+215
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ProjectIndex;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/DependencyContext;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/PhaseRecorder;)V+6
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Ljava/util/List;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ProjectIndex;)V+60
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ReactorContext;Lorg/apache/maven/project/MavenProject;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/TaskSegment;)V+151
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ReactorContext;Lorg/apache/maven/project/MavenProject;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/TaskSegment;)V+7
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ReactorContext;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ProjectBuildList;Ljava/util/List;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ReactorBuildStatus;)V+77
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;)V+336
j  org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionRequest;)Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionResult;+557
j  org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionRequest;)Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionResult;+11
j  org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(Lorg/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli$CliRequest;)I+19
j  org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(Lorg/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli$CliRequest;)I+61
j  org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main([Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/ClassWorld;)I+18
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced([Ljava/lang/String;)V+45
j  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch([Ljava/lang/String;)V+2
j  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode([Ljava/lang/String;)I+101
j  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the stacktrace, that error happens even before the GWT compiler is involved: when the gwt-maven-plugin tries to identify whether the modules need to be recompiled or not (or actually if they should be compiled at all: the plugin skips compilation if there are no entry-points).

The algorithm is likely flawed (e.g. it excludes inherited modules whose name start with `com.google.gwt.` but that could include modules from dependencies –e.g. GIN– and there are modules in GWT proper that aren't in this hierarchy –but in `com.google.web.bindery`–) and possibly buggy, but I'd say in this case it chokes on a malformed JAR or something similar.

Maybe try cleaning your local repo (`~/.m2/repository`) to re-download the dependencies?

Alternatively, run Maven with the `mvnDebug` command and attach a debugger to it, setting a break-point somewhere in the methods identified in the stacktrace to try to find out which JAR could be corrupt (at least which one makes the JVM crash)

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that helps.  Due to the intermittent nature I can't easily do the debug.  However, I can review plugin source perhaps or increment from 2.5.1.rc4 to 2.5.1 which should be safe.  Right now, I'm working on getting an easily reproducible case.  At 2 hour per iteration test where I can't be sure of failure prevents cycle testing